# Making changes to UI permanent in iTerm (iTerm2)

Tags: macos, zsh, iterm2

I am new to the MacOS, and I have started using iTerm, and I want to make the changes to my UI permanent, but I am unable to do so.

When I "right-click" in the iTerm window and go to `Edit Session... > Preferences>Text>Cursor>Vertical Bar`, my current instance of iTerm does what I want it to.

However, when I shut it down and start another window some time later, it reverts back to its old settings. How do I make these settings permanent so I don't have to keep repeating the above process?

Also, I have switched from using zsh to using bash, however, I still see this when I open an instance of terminal:

```
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
```

Isn't my default terminal now bash, not zsh?

Comment: How did you switch from using `zsh` to using `bash`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of right-clicking and entering "Edit Session...", you can make permanent changes from the navigation bar on the top of your screen once you open the iTerm.

iTerm2 > Preferences > Profiles > Text > Cursor > Vertical Bar.

Answer (score 0):

When the above didn't work for me, I found (from iTerm2 menu bar):

<kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>General</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd>

Where I had set *Save Changes* to *Manually*. Right next to that setting is the <kbd>Save Now</kbd> button.